# enabling custom fields in admin?

Tags: custom-field

i've found out that there are custom fields but i'm not able to activate them in the admin panel .. :(
i've checked the screen options but there's no custom fields - looks like it depends on the template i'm using.
any ideas how to modify it in order to enable custom fields for posts?

thx

Comment: When you say no custom fields - do you mean that even if you check it in the screen options, the meta box does not even appear? Or that it does show, but there is no custom field *data*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visibility of custom fields on the post edit screen is controlled on the post edit page.  There's a button called "Screen Options" towards the top of the screen.

[image: Screen Options Button]

Clicking that button will display all of the available boxes and panels for the edit page.  If custom fields is not visible here, then either your theme or a plug-in is disabling the feature.

[image: Screen Options Panel]