# custom fields cannt be seen with version 3.1

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-enqueue-script

I had a Theme that worked OK with ver 2.7. Now that I upgraded to 3.1; I cannot see the "custom fields" in the posts(may be hidden??). Can someone help.Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [enabling custom fields in admin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12088/enabling-custom-fields-in-admin)

Answer (score 2):

WordPress 3.1 hides some of these options.  If you go to edit a post, look on the upper right of your screen.  You will see "screen options."  From there, you can click custom fields (as well as other options).