# How to enable Custom Fields that are disabled by theme?

Tags: custom-field

Some one already asked that [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12088/enabling-custom-fields-in-admin), but that doesn't solve my problem.

My theme disabling the custom fields. How I can enable it manually? I want to know that which code Wordpress use to show Custom fields widget? Please help.

Update: Actually this is educational theme that create some new Posting options which are "Course", "Lesson" & "Testimonial". I want to bring custom fields there.

[image: Newly created posting methods]
[image: Now custom fields option]

`Fuctions.php`:

```
    <?php
//Error reporting
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR);

//Define constants
define('SITE_URL', home_url().'/');
define('AJAX_URL', admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
define('THEME_PATH', get_template_directory().'/');
define('THEME_URI', get_template_directory_uri().'/');
define('THEME_CSS_URI', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/');
define('THEMEX_PATH', THEME_PATH.'framework/');
define('THEMEX_URI', THEME_URI.'framework/');

//Set content width
$content_width=1140;

//Load language files
load_theme_textdomain('academy', THEME_PATH.'languages');

//Include theme functions
include(THEMEX_PATH.'functions.php');

//Include theme configuration file
include(THEMEX_PATH.'config.php');

//Include core class
include(THEMEX_PATH.'classes/themex.core.php');

//Init theme
$theme=new ThemexCore($config);
```

Comment: What is the name of your theme?

Comment: You need to show us the code that your theme uses. Look into the file `functions.php`. Also, can you post a screenshot of your screen options?

Comment: @Sven "Academy" bougth from themeforest. I urgently need answer so post question here.

Comment: @there is no relation with `functions.php` please see update

Comment: Well, if there's no relation with functions.php, with what does it relates?

Comment: @brasofilo that is thing that I want to know. Any way let see code.

Comment: Have you tried any plugin like "Advanced Custom Field" or "More Fields" other than the default custom fields of WordPress? I found ACF excellent than the default CF usability. Try a plugin like this and let's know it works or not.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam I try ACF but its not working

Comment: Perhaps you'll need to enable `'supports' => array( custom-fields )`

Comment: Have you tried [googling "how to disable custom field"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+disable+custom+field)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [Child Theme, Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php) or [Must Use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) plugin, and use [`add_post_type_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support):

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Add CF to CPTs */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'add_cpt_support_wpse_116891' );

function add_cpt_support_wpse_116891(){
    # See /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=SLUG
    add_post_type_support( 'SLUG-POST-TYPE-1', array( 'custom-fields' ) );
    add_post_type_support( 'SLUG-POST-TYPE-2', array( 'custom-fields' ) );
    add_post_type_support( 'SLUG-POST-TYPE-3', array( 'custom-fields' ) );
}
```

Comment: Please create make plugin. I create one but it is not working.

Comment: I had do the following but its look not working. What I am doing wrong?

`<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My custom Plugin
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
Author: John Doe
Author URI: http://example.com
License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function(){
    add_post_type_support( 'Course', array( 'custom-fields' ) );
    add_post_type_support( 'Lesson', array( 'custom-fields' ) );
    add_post_type_support( 'Testimonial', array( 'custom-fields' ) );
});
?>`

Comment: That is URL `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=lesson`. What is slug in it?

Comment: Sorry, I write 'Lesson' rather then 'lesson'. Now its working. Thanks you very much

Comment: The plugin work fine on localhost but when I upload it on my website i got this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home1/tissosas/public_html/asanpaisa.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/custom field adder.php on line 11` That is why?

Comment: Well, you just discovered that your host is not using PHP5.3+ :/ Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks you. I am wondring about hostgators hosting. That does not support latest php